# Вынести метод нахождения минимального и максимального элемента коллекции в отдельный класс. Java

Tags: java

Стоит задача найти элементы коллекции различных геометрических фигур с максимальной и минимальной площадью.

Имеется интерфейс Shape.java:

```
package info.sjd;

public interface Shape {

    double getArea();
}
```

Далее класс AbstractShape.java:

```
package info.sjd;

public abstract class AbstractShape implements Shape {

    public abstract double getArea();

}
```

Далее классы отдельных фигур, не буду каждый приводить, только круг, например circle/Circle.java:

```
package info.sjd.circle;

import info.sjd.AbstractShape;

public class Circle extends AbstractShape {

    private int radius;

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }  

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return (double) (Math.PI*radius*radius);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(Math.PI*radius*radius);
    }
}
```

В AppRunnerCollection.java мы задаем полям имеющихся фигур различные значения, вычисляем их площадь и затем находим минимум максимум:

```
package info.sjd;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import info.sjd.circle.Circle;
import info.sjd.rectangle.Rectangle;
import info.sjd.square.Square;
import info.sjd.triangle.Triangle;
import info.sjd.triangle2.Triangle2;

public class AppRunnerCollection {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppRunnerCollection.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Finding Square Area

        Square square1 = new Square();
        square1.setSide(15);

        // Finding Circle Area

        Circle circle1 = new Circle();
        circle1.setRadius(1);

        // Finding Rectangle Area       

        Rectangle rectangle11 = new Rectangle();
        rectangle11.setWidth(15);
        rectangle11.setHeight(20);

        // Finding Triangle Area through three sides

        Triangle triangle11 = new Triangle();
        triangle11.setaSide(3);
        triangle11.setbSide(4);
        triangle11.setcSide(5);

        // Finding Triangle Area through its base and height

        Triangle2 triangle21 = new Triangle2();
        triangle21.setBase(10);
        triangle21.setHeight(5);

        // Creating collection

        List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
        shapes.add(square1);
        shapes.add(circle1);
        shapes.add(rectangle11);
        shapes.add(triangle11);
        shapes.add(triangle21);

        logger.info("Our collection contains the following elements: ");

        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
            logger.info("The object belongs to the type " + shape.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and its square equals to " + shape.toString());
        }

        // Finding the minimal and maximal elements of collection

        Shape maxElement = null, minElement = null;

        if (!shapes.isEmpty()) {
            maxElement = shapes.get(0);
            minElement = shapes.get(0);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
            if (maxElement.getArea() < shapes.get(i).getArea()) {
                maxElement = shapes.get(i);
            }

            if (minElement.getArea() > shapes.get(i).getArea()) {
                minElement = shapes.get(i);
            }

        }

        logger.info("The minimal square object is " + minElement.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", its square equals to " + minElement.toString() + ".\n\t The maximum square object is " + maxElement.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", its square equals to " + maxElement.toString() + ".");


    }
}
```

Как теперь сделать красиво, чтобы избавиться от этой простыни и иметь возможность провести юнит-тесты для методов, возвращающих элементы с минимальной и максимальной площадью?

Я понимаю, что надо создать отдельные классы MinSquare.java и MaxSquare.java, которые бы содержали методы minSquare() и maxSquare(), например так - **здесь много ошибок, я об этом знаю**:

```
package info.sjd.minsquare;

import info.sjd.Shape;

public class MinSquare {
    public MinSquare() {
        Shape minElement = null;

        if (!shapes.isEmpty()) {
            minElement = shapes.get(0);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
            if (minElement.getArea() > shapes.get(i).getArea()) {
                minElement = shapes.get(i);
            }
        }
        return minElement;
    }
}
```

Но IDE выдаёт столько ошибок, что я не знаю, за что хвататься.

Как синтаксически правильно вынести эти два метода в отдельные классы?

Comment: Зачем вам эти классы MinSquare.java и MaxSquare.java. Создайте два метода, куда будете передавать коллекцию фигур, а на выходе получать значение максимальной/минимальной площади. Там за один стрим управиться можно, будет красиво и лаконично

Comment: Слышал, что подобные методы выносятся в отдельный класс с сервисами в пакете. Но подробностей мне так и не рассказали.

Answer (score 1):

Если принципиально нужен отдельный сервис с методами, то можно создать такой класс:

```
public class ShapeService {

    public Shape getShapeWithMinSquare(List<Shape> shapes) {
        if (shapes.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return shapes.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Shape::getArea)).orElse(null);
    }

    public Shape getShapeWithMaxSquare(List<Shape> shapes) {
        if (shapes.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return shapes.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Shape::getArea)).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Тогда измените ваш код в `AppRunnerCollection` вот так:

```
// Finding the minimal and maximal elements of collection

        ShapeService shapeService = new ShapeService();

        Shape maxElement = shapeService.getShapeWithMaxSquare(shapes);
        Shape minElement = shapeService.getShapeWithMinSquare(shapes);

        if (minElement != null) {
            logger.info("The minimal square object is " + minElement.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", its square equals to " + minElement.toString() + ".");
        }

        if (maxElement != null) {
            logger.info("The maximum square object is " + maxElement.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", its square equals to " + maxElement.toString() + ".");
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо. С компаратором еще не работал, поэтому перепишу методы по нахождению минимального и максимального элементов через цикл for.

Comment: @VitaliyTretyakov, они неплохо уменьшают простыню) Успехов!

Comment: Да, согласен, но до этого еще дойти надо. Пока не буду использовать то, что не до конца понимаю.